# How add values in JSON to get a cumulative total using Dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a json object that has the memory, cpu and number of replicas for each API in the system.

I need to calculate the total CPU and Memory where the CPU / Memory for each API is cpu * number fo replicas. Take a look at the following input JSON

```
var payload = [
    {
        "id": "5a9b06b3-ed2c-4382-cf41427b6f56",
        "name": "api-1",
        "cpuReserved": 0.2,
        "cpuLimit": 0.5,
        "memReserved": 2,
        "memLimit": 2,
        "replicas": 1,
        "status": "RUNNING"
    },
    {
        "id": "79a90d5e-d042-9a6c-61cbe1341d04",
        "name": "api-2",
        "cpuReserved": 0.2,
        "cpuLimit": 1,
        "memReserved": 2,
        "memLimit": 2,
        "replicas": 2,
        "status": "RUNNING"
    },
    {
        "id": "15d0e51f-198c-948c-c4c864a5dd72",
        "name": "api-3",
        "cpuReserved": 0.2,
        "cpuLimit": 0.5,
        "memReserved": 2,
        "memLimit": 2,
        "replicas": 1,
        "status": "RUNNING"
    }
]
```

The output required is something like this:

```
"report": {
      "count": 3,
      "totalCPULimit": 3,
      "totalCPUReserved": 0.8,
      "totalMemReserved": 8,
      "totalMemLimit": 8
    }
```

**Note: out of the 3 APIS in the input; 1 API has 2 replicas while the other 2 APIs have 1 replica each.**

How can I generate this output using Dataweave in MuleSoft 4?

Comment: Have you attempted to do this before coming to StackOverflow? If so, then please provide any relevant code and any errors you may be getting.

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a free code writing service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service). Furthermore, to help you, others need sufficient debugging details. Anyone can ask or answer on StackOverflow as long as they follow rules designed to make helping easier.

Comment: and yes, if am able to solve this then I will post the answer to my own question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty crude though it can get you to the desired:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var totals = payload map {
      a: $.cpuLimit * $.replicas,
      b: $.cpuReserved * $.replicas,
      c: $.memReserved * $.replicas,
      d: $.memLimit *$.replicas
}

---
"report": {
      "count": sizeOf(payload),
      "totalCPULimit": sum(totals.a),
      "totalCPUReserved": sum(totals.b),
      "totalMemReserved": sum(totals.c),
      "totalMemLimit": sum(totals.d),
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another way of doing it deriving from an XML transformation code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

---
    "report": {
      "count": sizeOf(payload) as String,
      "totalCPULimit": sum(payload map($.cpuLimit * $.replicas)),
      "totalCPUReserved": sum(payload map($.cpuReserved * $.replicas)),
      "totalMemReserved": sum(payload map($.memReserved * $.replicas)),
      "totalMemLimit": sum(payload map($.memLimit * $.replicas)),
    } 
]
```

Comment: You are iterating the whole array 4 different times.

Comment: Good catch, may be the first answer is the better one